# Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. webpack install by "npm install webpack"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am learning on React-JS. I have written a simple project. But getting an error when I run "npm start" command.

My Webpack.config.js file is given below--

---

```
var webpack= require("webpack");
var path =require("path");

var DIST_DIR= path.resolve(__dirname, 
"dist");
 var SRC_DIR= path.resolve(__dirname, 
 "src");

 var config={
 entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
 output:{
    path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
    file: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/app/"
},
module:{
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js?/,
            include: SRC_DIR,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query:{
                presets: ["react", 
"es2015", "stage-2"]
            }
        }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports=config;
```

---

package.json file --

---

```
{
  "name": "basic-reactjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Some Basic ReactJS",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "npm run build",
  "build": "webpack -d && cp 
        src/index.html dist/index.html 
       && webpack-dev-server --content- 
       base src/ --inline --hot",
  "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp 
     src/index.html dist/index.html"
       },
  "keywords": [
   "reactjs"
  ],
  "author": "Numery Zaber",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.6.3",
  "react-dom": "^16.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
  "webpack": "^4.26.0",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
}
```

---

Webpack install by the follwoing command

npm install webpack webpack-dev-server babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react babel-preset-stage-2 --save-dev

Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The schema in Webpack 4 is now changed.You have imported the loaders which was working in older version of webpack.

For more details : https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/

```
var webpack= require("webpack");
var path =require("path");

var DIST_DIR= path.resolve(__dirname, 
"dist");
 var SRC_DIR= path.resolve(__dirname, 
 "src");

 var config={
 entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
 output:{
    path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/app/"
},
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ["react","es2015", "stage-2"], 
        },
      }
    }
  ]
}
};

module.exports=config;
```

You can also use @babel/preset-env.

Comment: Thank's for you help. I use your Webpack.config.js file. But getting the same error.

Comment: @Nick can you check once more. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Some improvement. But now I am getting different error.. ----
ERROR in ./src/app/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
 babel-loader@8 requires Babel 7.x (the package '@babel/core'). If you'd like to use Babel 6.x ('babel-core'), you should install 'babel-loader@7'.   Do I need to install Babel7 or anything else.

Comment: @Nick yes you need to install the babel loader npm i babel-loader --save

Comment: @Nick you can instal babel loader via "npm i babel-loader --save" command

Comment: Can you show me the latest error ? till then I will try to create a setup with same config.

Comment: ERROR in ./src/app/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
 babel-loader@8 requires Babel 7.x (the package '@babel/core'). If you'd like to use Babel 6.x ('babel-core'), you should install 'babel-loader@7'.
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)

Comment: ERROR in ./src/app/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /home/numery/Desktop/ReactJS/Basic-ReactJS/node_modules/babel-preset-react/lib/index.js
    at createDescriptor (/home/numery/Desktop/ReactJS/Basic-ReactJS/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178:11)

Comment: Have you installed all the babel packages that you have imported ?

Comment: I run all the command in the terminal. What else should I do?

Comment: Do I need to make any change on webpack.config.js file? There is no version declare for the babel-loader

Comment: dependencies are --------------------------------"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.26.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  }

Comment: Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: @Nick,  you need to install one more dependency : npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react

Comment: Still same error. Dependencies are -------------------------------------"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.26.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  }

Comment: Can anyone help please?